# how to compute the angle of tilt of ellipse or ellipsoid

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, vectors, matlab

i need you help in solving the following problem:

given the "center form" of ellipsoid:

- A : matrix of d*d where d is the dimension
- c : center of the ellipsoid hold in a vector

how can i compute the angle of tilt of the ellipsoid from these two inputs in Matlab?
And how can i compute the angle between 2 axes i.e. the axes of the ellipsoid and the axes of the coordinate system?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See also the earlier post "[Computing angle of ellipse or ellipsoid](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1425925/237)."

Answer (score 1):

Following [this post of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1217797/35416), the eigenvectors of your matrix $A$ will form a rotation matrix which turns a rotated ellipse into its axis-aligned (i.e. diagonal matrix) analogon, and vice versa. This generalizes to higher dimensions.

To read the angle from that matrix, follow [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Rotation_matrix_.E2.86.94_Euler_axis.2Fangle) on how to turn a rotation matrix into an axis and angle representation. Unfortunately, the formula you obtain from this doesn't generalize to other dimensions.