# Equation curves

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

Introduce equation curves to the canonical form, finding an appropriate rectangular coordinate system.

a) $5x^2+12xy-22x-12y-19=0$

b) $9x^2+24xy+16y^2-230x+110y-475=0$

Could somebody do one task. I don't know how i must do this. Maybe you write in points what I must do? Please help me!

Comment: Is the question: "Identify which conic is described by the equation and if so, find its main characteristics (center if it exists, main axis...)" If so, there should be examples in your textbook or in your notes, showing how to first find the rotation which will describe the conic in a rectangular system and then transform the equation to its canonical form.

Comment: See also [Compute center, axes and rotation from equation of ellipse](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1217796/35416).