# Construction of two Focus for conic section with five points

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, geometric-construction

Using an unnumbered ruler and a caliper you should Construction of two Focus for conic section with five points.

The difficulty is that the conic is not drawn, only the five points must be used
[image]

I was interested in this question in the past and I am asking it now for the sake of knowledge sharing because I think there are a lot of people who are interested in getting the build steps, I will not put the full details of the solutions because it will be too long but I will put simple signs and graphics, you can add more details in the other answers...

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2070274/graphically-locate-the-axes-or-foci-of-an-ellipse-from-5-arbitrary-points-on-its/4393709#4393709

Comment: Nice, different methods were used there

Comment: See also this answer, where I discuss how to construct the axes: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4720458/255730

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

A conic section is uniquely defined by five distinct points on its circumference because two different conic sections cannot intersect at more than four points.

The elements of a conic section can be constructed with the knowledge of five of its points analytically, but this does not mean that it cannot be done geometrically, although the construction is difficult - and a challenge - but it can be done with the traditional tools of geometry, the ruler and the compass.

To solve the big problem, we will solve a series of step-by-step problems:

1. Create a sixth point at a random position.
   This is done using Pascal's theorem
   [image]
2. Constructing a chord passing through a known point and parallel to a known straight line.
   [image]
3. Create the center of the conical cut.
   This is done based on the following theorem: The midpoints of parallel strings in a conic section pass through a center
   [image]
4. Create a tangent to a point.
   Where the tangent is considered a special feature of the hypotenuse
   [image]
   Tangent can also be created using Pascal's theorem
   [image]
5. Create two conjugated chords.
   This construct relies on the use of affine shunts
   [image]
6. Determine the two axes of symmetry of the segments.
   You can see the [following link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rytz%27s_construction)

[image]
7. Create two symmetrical tangents with respect to the axis of symmetry, then create the two foci.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Finally, I apologize for the bad language as I write using Google Translate. Feel free to edit the text if you find this necessary

Comment: Which software do you use to produce your figures ?

Comment: I design the original geometric drawing using Geogebra, then I place the Geogebra drawing as a layer in a photo editor and manually recreate the elements using it. Here is the link to the application: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iudesk.android.photo.editor.

Comment: Thanks for the information.