# Constructing the foci of the conic through five given points, using straightedge and compass

Tags: euclidean-geometry, conic-sections, geometric-construction

> Given 5 points (every 5 points define a conic) find the foci of their conic using straightedge and compass construction.

I thought about this question a while ago and can't solve it. Hypothetically it's equivalent to finding roots of a quadratic, so it should be solvable but I'm not certain how. Algebraic approach seems like an awful thing to do here, so please don't unless certain there is no other way.

Comment: see   Dorrie, 100 Great Problems  of Elementary Mathematics

Comment: section 64 is a conic section from five points. Page 273 in the Dover edition

Comment: That involution theorem is very interesting! But it doesn't answer my question. But God I never knew about that book and it's quite interesting. I'll put a read to it.

Comment: The algebraic approach is not so ugly: you can find the general equation of the conic by solving a $5\times5$ system and then compute the foci as explained here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44391/foci-of-a-general-conic-equation/2103844#2103844

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Graphically locate the axes or foci of an ellipse from 5 arbitrary points on its perimeter.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2070274/graphically-locate-the-axes-or-foci-of-an-ellipse-from-5-arbitrary-points-on-its)

Comment: Marking as duplicate, but I like the answer here; those threads should be merged.

Answer (score 2):

I'll show a possible (lengthy) solution below. I'm not going to prove all the constructions involved, but I can add some explanation on request.

**We start by finding the lines tangent to the conic at three points**.
Let $ABCDE$ be the five given points (see figure below). We can use [Pascal's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_theorem) to find the line tangent to the conic at $A$: if $F$ is the intersection of $AB$ with $CD$, and $G$ is the intersection of $AC$ with $BE$, then the intersection $T_A$ of $FG$ with $DE$ is a point on the tangent at $A$ to the conic $ABCDE$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3828262/require-a-proof-for-intelligenti-paucas-method-to-compute-an-ellipse/3828379#3828379) for a detailed proof). Repeat the same construction to find the lines tangent to the conic at $B$ and $C$ (red in the figure).

**We can now find the center of the conic**.
Let $H$ be the intersection of the lines tangent at $A$ and $B$, and $L$ the intersection of the lines tangent at $B$ and $C$. If $M$ and $N$ are the midpoints of segments $AB$ and $BC$, then the center $O$ of the conic is the intersection of lines $HM$ and $LN$ (this is due to a another well-wknon theorem: center, midpoint of a chord and intersection of the tangents at the endpoints of the chord are collinear). If lines $HM$ and $LN$ are parallel then the conic is a **parabola**: in that case draw another tangent at $D$ and construct the focus [as explained here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4687444/255730).

[image]

**Let's now construct two semi-conjugate diameters of the conic**.
Having found the center $O$, draw through $B$ a line parallel to the tangent at $A$ (see figure below), intersecting line $OA$ at $P$. Draw then through $O$ a line parallel to the tangent at $A$ and a point $K$ on it such that

$$
OK={OA\cdot BP \over \sqrt{|OA^2-OP^2|} }.
$$

Segments $OA$ and $OK$ form a couple of semi-conjugate diameters of the conic. The conic is an ellipse if $OA>OP$, while it is a hyperbola if $OA<OP$

[image]

**We can finally construct the foci of the conic**.
If the conic is an **ellipse** then you can find major and minor axes [as explained here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3321038/255730), and from them the foci.

If the conic is a **hyperbola**, then draw through $K$ the line parallel to $OA$ to meet at $Q$ the tangent through $A$, and reflect $Q$ about $A$ to $Q'$. Lines $OQ$, $OQ'$ are then the asymptotes of the hyperbola and its transverse axis is the bisector of $\angle QOQ'$ (green in figure below).

Foci $S$ and $S'$ are those points on the transverse axis lying at the same distance from $O$ and such that tangent $AQ$ is the bisector of $SAS'$. To construct them, draw from $A$ the line perpendicular to the transvere axis and reflect it about tangent $AQ$. Let then $R$ be the intersection of that reflected line with the perpendicular to the transverse axis from $O$. The circle through $A$ with center $R$ intersects then the transverse axis at $S$ and $S'$.

[image]

Comment: Could you summarize the argument?  Is the main point constructing the line $SS'$ through the points $S,S'$ on the circle centered at $R$, so as to identify the focus at $O$ as the intersection with a line previously constructed?

Comment: @MikhailKatz We want to construct the FOCI of a conic section, given five points on it. In the first part I constructed the center $O$ of the conic and a pair of conjugate diameters. Then I constructed the axes and foci, with two different constructions for ellipses and hyperbolas.

Comment: Can you clarify at what point exactly you need to use the compass?

Comment: @MikhailKatz To find  and , the midpoints of segments  and .

Comment: @Intelligentipauca I really like the approach you took in constructing the tangents to the 5 points. It's really cool to use pascals theoram on two points which are the same point. Cool argument and the rest is also cool.