# one only conic can be drawn having any two parallel chords

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

I need to prove the following theorem:

**Theorem** Only one conic can be drawn having any two given parallel chords and its centre is at any point on the line bisecting the chords.

I tried to prove it using Analytic Geometry, but I failled. I supposed that the point $P_1(x_1,y_1)$ is in the first chord, that $(a,b)$ is a fixed direction and that the $x$-axis is the axis of the conic. In this way, the center is $C(c,0)$.

I found the point $V_1(x_1-\frac{a}{b}y_1,0)$ as the intersection between the chord and the axis. More than that, $Q_1(x_1-2\frac{a}{b}y_1,-y_1)$ is another intersection between the conic and the chord.

The same procedures can be done for the second chord, getting the points $P_2(x_2,y_2)$, $V_2(x_2-\frac{a}{b}y_2,0)$ (intersection between the chord and the axis) and $Q_2(x_2-2\frac{a}{b}y_2,-y_2)$ (intersection between the conic and the chord).

Thanks for any help.

Cleto

Answer (score 1):

A [well-known property of conics](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/ParallelChordsInEllipse.shtml) states that the midpoints of parallel chords lie on a line passing through the center.

Hence, given two parallel chords $AB$, $CD$ and the line passing through their midpoints, once you choose the center $O$ on that line the conic is fixed: if $A'$ is the reflection of $A$ about $O$, then there is a unique conic through $ABCDA'$ and that conic has $O$ as its center.

EDIT.

As noted by Blue in a comment, the theorem is false in the special case $AB\cong CD$, if center $O$ is chosen at the center of parallelogram $ABDC$: in that case any conic through $ABCD$ satisfies the given conditions. If center $O$ is not the center of parallelogram $ABDC$, the conic is unique but degenerates into a pair of parallel lines.

Comment: One quibble: It's possible that reflections of the given chord endpoints about chosen center $O$ don't give any new points. This happens when, and only when, $\square ABCD$ is a parallelogram and $O$ is the intersection of its diagonals. In such a case, the conic is not uniquely determined by $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, and $O$. So, the theorem, as stated in the question, is false. It can be saved by, say, requiring the given parallel chords to be non-congruent.

Comment: @blue You are right: if $ABCD$ is a parallelogram and center $O$ is the intersection of its diagonals, then infinitely many conics are possible. But if $O$ is not the intersection of the diagonals, then a unique (degenerate) conic exists: a couple of parallel lines.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Where is the point $E$ in your construction? $A, B, C$ and $D$ are given, $A'$ is the reflection, and $E$? Thanks!

Comment: @CletoPereira It was a typo, sorry! I've just corrected it.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca and Blue. Thanks for your comments. I proved the result that midpoints of parallel chords lie on a line passing through the center. It was something new for me. But I can't use the five points theorem because it is just the main result I need to prove. I'm studying the article https://www.jstor.org/stable/3602341?seq=1 If you have another approach to my problem, please let me know! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @CletoPereira Why don't you follow the proof given there?

Comment: @CletoPereira Moreover, the five-point theorem can be proved in many different ways (its first proof goes back to Euclid, IIRC). Why do you want to follow that paper?

Comment: @Intelligentipauca do you have any simple proof to indicate me? I really didn't know anything about the result and it was new for me. As I found this article, i followed it. But unfortunatelly it is very difficult to understanding it and the notation used is complicated. If you have another indication, please let me know! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @CletoPereira If you want a geometric construction for the conic through five points, then you can read [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3745328/255730). The last part can be changed if needed, to construct the axes instead of computing their lengths.

Comment: See also this wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_points_determine_a_conic