# Determining how accurate an ellipse fit is

Tags: geometry, statistics, algebraic-geometry, mathematical-physics, mathematical-modeling

So I have an image of bacteria particles which are often shaped very irregularly with many grooves. Im trying to fit ellipses onto these particles so I can get a better, more smooth analysis of the data. But I would like to know; is it possible to calculate how good of a fit the ellipse is? Since the ellipse is basically a shape being fitted to a set of points that form an irregular polygon, its similar to a linear regression. Is there a similar thing to find the fit of a fitting shape?

Comment: This may be helpful: [Ellipse fitting methods.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/151969)